# Too much spacing between subsection and custom itemize

Tags: spacing, sectioning, lists, resume

I have a resume I created using [`resume.cls`](http://people.debian.org/~dburrows/resume-cls/resume.cls). I have a custom `nitemize` environment in order to remove separation between items within the document itself. In the document, under one of my internships, I have subsections and then an `nitemize` under each subsection. I cannot for the life of me remove the whitespace between the beginning and end of the `nitemize`.

I have read the first 3 pages of the Google results for my problem, and nothing seems to work, I think it is because I am using a different `.cls` maybe, or I am missing some packages or something.

If you need to see the `.cls` file or my `.tex` file, I would be happy to provide it.

Here is the minimal example of the document:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{resume}
\usepackage{paralist}
\definecolor{ruleendcolor}{rgb}{0.6, 0.6, 0.6}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\linespread{0}



\setlength{\parskip}{0\parsep}

\newenvironment{nitemize}{
 \begin{itemize}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{
 \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{Linux Development}
\begin{nitemize}
\item Planned and designed a customized thin client OS based on Linux
\item Utilized a virtual environment to compare several different prototypes
\item Designed an unattended distribution method for customized Linux installs
\item Developed custom configuration scripts to simplify user experience
\item Facilitated initial user testing
\end{nitemize}
\subsection{Virtualized Infrastructure Analysis}
\begin{nitemize}
\item Maintained Navistar's Virtual Desktop Infrastructure using Citrix Desktop Studio and Microsoft VMM
\item Deployed packages using System Center Configuration Manager
\item Able to diagnose problems using knowledge of VLANs, Remote Distribution Points, Powershell Scripting
\item Made a proposal to implement Xen's dynamic resource allocation features to save money and provide a better user experience
\end{nitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), since these things may be dependent on a lot of things - usage of code, or the class itself, or other packages.

Comment: Thanks, I added the pastebin links. Is that OK, or should I avoid having outside links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with the help of the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

Define your `nitemize` environment as

```
\newenvironment{nitemize}{%
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]%
}{%
  \end{itemize}%
}
```

and the code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{resume}
\usepackage{paralist}
\definecolor{ruleendcolor}{rgb}{0.6, 0.6, 0.6}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\linespread{0}

%\setlength{\parskip}{0\parsep}

\newenvironment{nitemize}{%
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]%
}{%
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{Linux Development}
\begin{nitemize}
\item Planned and designed a customized thin client OS based on Linux
\item Utilized a virtual environment to compare several different prototypes
\item Designed an unattended distribution method for customized Linux installs
\item Developed custom configuration scripts to simplify user experience
\item Facilitated initial user testing
\end{nitemize}
\subsection{Virtualized Infrastructure Analysis}
\begin{nitemize}
\item Maintained Navistar's Virtual Desktop Infrastructure using Citrix Desktop Studio and Microsoft VMM
\item Deployed packages using System Center Configuration Manager
\item Able to diagnose problems using knowledge of VLANs, Remote Distribution Points, Powershell Scripting
\item Made a proposal to implement Xen's dynamic resource allocation features to save money and provide a better user experience
\end{nitemize}

\end{document}
```

will output

[image]

while this is the result with your original code

[image]

Note that, as Werner points out, you can substitute the `\newenvironment` definition with

```
\newlist{nitemize}{itemize}{1} 
\setlist[nitemize]{topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,label=\textbullet}
```

which is more *in line* with the `enumitem` package.

Replacing `topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt` with `nosep` you also have `partopsep=0pt` which removes further space, but I wouldn't do that since the result (IMHO) is not as good.

Comment: Perhaps more in line with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) would be: `\newlist{nitemize}{itemize}{1} \setlist[nitemize]{nosep,label=\textbullet}`

Comment: @Werner thanks for the suggestion, I've added it in the answer. Anyway I won't use `nosep` otherwise the subsection and the rest are too close.

Comment: You're a genius!!! I appreciate the assistance more than you know. LaTeX is so cool, I'm trying to get my school's career development office to recommend it to their decently intelligent students for resumes.

Comment: @SamFrench You are too much kind... Happy to help.